# Join daily data with monthly data MS-Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having trouble joining daily data (that has been aggregated to monthly data) with monthly data. I have a financial database in excel with two tables:

1. Outlays - All purchases with category and date (day/month/year) when the purchase was made
2. Income - monthly income by date (month/year)

I have a query that is summing daily outlays and grouping them by month:

```
SELECT Format(Outlays.period,"mmm-yy") AS Period, Sum(Outlays.Value) AS [Living Cost]
FROM Outlays
GROUP BY Format(Outlays.period,"mmm-yy"), Outlays.[Living Cost]
HAVING (((Outlays.[Living Cost])=True));
```

Where I am running into trouble is joining the income data to this query:

```
SELECT Format(Outlays.period,"mmm-yy") AS Period, Sum(Outlays.Value) AS [Living Cost]
FROM Outlays
JOIN Income ON Outlays.period = Income.Period
GROUP BY Format(Outlays.period,"mmm-yy"), Outlays.[Living Cost]
HAVING (((Outlays.[Living Cost])=True));
```

This query returns "syntax error in the FROM clause".

Any ideas on the correct syntax would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access SQL, you need to explicitly declare the type of `JOIN` and not leave it generically as `JOIN`. Whereas in other RDMS's, `JOIN` alone defaults to `INNER JOIN`, in MS Access you must declare it.

```
FROM Outlays INNER JOIN Income ON Outlays.period = Income.Period
```

And for multiple joins, you must enclose table/query pairings in parentheses:

```
FROM ((Outlays 
INNER JOIN Income ON Outlays.period = Income.Period)
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON Outlays.id = OtherTable.id)
INNER JOIN AnotherTable ON Outlays.id = AnotherTable.id
```

Comment: I always suggest the query builder to new users.